# file system not taking precedence over htaccess RewriteRule?

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

I want my RewriteRule to not take effect if there is an actual file matching the surfer's request within the file system.  So if someone goes to mysite.com/realfile.php?foo=bar, and realfile.php is a real file, the surfer gets served realfile.php?foo=bar.  But if someone goes to mysite.com/nonexistentfile.php and nonexistentfile.php is not a real file, then the RewriteRule should interpret and pass the request to process.php

I have the following in my .htaccess:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ process.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

This works IF there is no real file in the file system matching the surfer's request.  It does not work if the surfer enters realfile.php?foo=bar...in that case they hit the RewriteRule.  It does work if they just do realfile.php, but I want query strings still get passed to the real file if it exists.  I thought the local file system always took precedence over RewriteRule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might suggest something such as the following (similar to what WordPress uses):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

The -f flag checks for an existing file, the -d flag checks for a directory - so it will apply the rewrite if the request is not for a file or directory.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f is what did it, thanks!  For some reason I thought it just defaulted to always serving the local file if it exists- guess not!